# How to add bootsector to CD using linux?

Tags: nasm, bootstrapping

How do I write a bootsector to a cd using linux? I made the boot sector in nasm and I have compiled the binary. I have tried to use dd from linux and I tried partcopy but nothing is working, not even masteriso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `dd`. Try this:

```
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc bs=512 count=1 if=mybootloader.bin of=/dev/cddevice
```

Replace `cddevice` with your `/dev` entry for the CD, or with the name of a disk image file.